# INSERT ALL with conditions PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to do is write an INSERT statement with three different conditions.

Here is what I have made so far (but this code gets an ORA-00913 too many values error):

```
INSERT ALL
   WHEN SALARY > 20000 THEN
     INTO SPECIAL_SAL13(EMPLOYEE_ID,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,SALARY)
   WHEN SALARY <= 20000 THEN
     INTO SAL_HISTORY13(EMPLOYEE_ID,SALARY)
   WHEN SALARY <= 20000 THEN
     INTO MGR_HISTORY13(EMPLOYEE_ID,MANAGER_ID,SALARY)
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID < 125
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
INSERT ALL
   WHEN SALARY > 20000 THEN
     INTO SPECIAL_SAL13(EMPLOYEE_ID,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,SALARY)
     VALUES(EMPLOYEE_ID,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,SALARY)
   WHEN SALARY <= 20000 THEN
     INTO SAL_HISTORY13(EMPLOYEE_ID,SALARY)
     VALUES(EMPLOYEE_ID,SALARY)
   WHEN SALARY <= 20000 THEN
     INTO MGR_HISTORY13(EMPLOYEE_ID,MANAGER_ID,SALARY)
     VALUES(EMPLOYEE_ID,MANAGER_ID,SALARY)
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID < 125
```

For reference see [here](http://psoug.org/reference/insert.html).

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I needed :) Thanks a lot in sec will accept answer:)